# EAGLView with transparent background?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

How should I make a cocos3D scene transparent (EAGLView with transparent background)? I know this gonna be a repeated question. **BUT I’ve tried all suggestions from various sources, but non of them worked for me**.

Just listing them up here as a reference:

1) Changed the opaque and clear color in the setGLDefaultValues method in CCDirector.m

```
 openGLView_.opaque = NO;
 glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

2) In EAGLView initWithCoder

```
CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*)[self layer];

    pixelformat_ = kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8;
    depthFormat_ = 0; // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES;
    multiSampling_= NO;
    requestedSamples_ = 0;
    size_ = [eaglLayer bounds].size;

    eaglLayer.opaque = NO;
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    const CGFloat myColor[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    eaglLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, myColor);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

    eaglLayer.drawableProperties = eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

    if( ! [self setupSurfaceWithSharegroup:nil] ) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }
```

3) Changed the isOverlayingDeviceCamera method of my CCViewController

```
viewController.isOverlayingDeviceCamera = YES;
```

I am using EAGLView.h version 1.3
I tried to use newer version (1.7), But I could not continue as it gives compiler errors with this import

```
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
```

Please give me a hand since I wasted my whole day with play around this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were mistaking the OpenGL clear color for the UIView clear color:

Instead of

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

use

```
openGLView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I did tried it in setGLDefaultValues. But does not work. Should I use a newer version of EAGLView classes instead of version 1.3?

Comment: Update: I tried openGLView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; Then it shows a RED background and suddenly turns to black again

Answer (score 0):

In **cocos3d 2.0**, have a look at the AppDelegate class in either the *hello, world* project template, or the `CC3DemoMashUp` demo app.

If you uncomment the line:

```
_viewController.isOverlayingDeviceCamera = YES;
```

it will do what you want.

Be sure to follow the pattern in those `AppDelegates` for creating the director, controller and view. In particular, with **cocos3d**, you should be using a `CC3UIViewController` (or subclass like `CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController` for showing the camera), and letting it configure and create the `CC3GLView`. Stay away from `EAGLView`, etc.

If you are using a version of **cocos3d** prior to **2.0**, again, it’s similar, and have a look at how the controllers and views are handled in the sample cocos3d `AppDelegates`.

Comment: The above two comments have nothing to do with the original question being answered. In future, please post a new question.

Comment: This seems broken Bill. I uncommented `_viewController.isOverlayingDeviceCamera = YES` in CC3DemoMashUpAppDelegate.m and `[self addBackdrop]` in CC3DemoMashUpScene.m but I don't see my camera replacing the blue sky.

Comment: I've just verified that it's working in the **Cocos3D 2.0.2** demo projects. With newer version of Cocos2D, you also need to set the background color of the 2D `CCScene` to transparent. Please follow the notes in the demo projects for examples. If you are using Storyboards, make sure you follow the notes in the `MainViewController openScene:` method in the `CC3DemoMultiScene` demo app, which explains how to configure the `UIViews` in your Storyboard file.